# How to make an exam timer continue after clicking next page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, timer

I am making an online exam but the timer part has a problem. Every time a user click on the next button to get a new page, the timer restarts. Here is my code. I am using laravel

http://paste.laravel.com/iOo

I also want to add the option of saving and exiting if one cannot complete the exam. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the session variable to send the time from one page to next page.

Comment: My questions are coming from the data base so i have loops to display the questions. I am confussed on how to apply sessions here.

Comment: Then how can you reach to other page, you means that you are showing the question on a single page. right.

Comment: No. i have several pages depending on the number of questions. i am using pagination to go to other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this way:

- When test starts, create an session variable for the current test for holding questions, for example, 'testQuestions'
- Create a function that will send json output containing a single question from 'testQuestions' array. So whenever you query that url with proper index, you get that question. you can also add additional information, such as nextQuestionIndex, prevQuestionIndex, etc., when sending that question. They will help you to crate Next and Previous buttons on frontend.
- Then on front-end, you can create multiple sections (or divs with IDs), one for displaying timer, one for displaying question.
- Then write function in JavaScript for click events on next and previous button. You can send ajax request and get json response containing next question. You can modify the content of current question to display next or previous question.

You can improve upon this strategy and submit the questions form when Next or Previous button is clicked. This way, you will be updating answer for a question and receiving next/previous question in the single call. Because you will be using ajax request, you can avoid page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can record the start time for the exam in a cookie and then each page can read that cookie when the page loads to see what the exam start time was.

Comment: Will cookies help me achieve save and exit when the user cannot finish the exam? Plus, my questions are coming from the data base so i have loops to display the questions. it gets confusing on how to apply a cookie...

Comment: @Mardwan - A cookie stores data for a particular page/site in the browser so it can be retrieved in the future by the same page or other pages in the site for this particular browser.  Whether it's useful for save and exit depends upon how you are saving the state of the exam which you have not described to us.  Are you storing exam state on a server?  Where do you intend to save/store the exam state?

Comment: The exam answers will have to be typed in by the user for later evaluation so i am saving on the server for later retrieval

Comment: @Mardwan - if your user logs in with a unique user ID, then you can just use that as the identifier in your server DB.  So, save and exit would only need to push all the data to the server for storage.  If your user doesn't log in, then you will need to set a cookie with a unique ID and use that as the storage identifier and the user will only be able to retrieve their questions from this particular browser.